# How to fetch corresponding rows from other table without inner loops in php

Tags: php, pdo

table_products - pid, pname

```
1 abc
2 xyz
3 mnop
```

table_variants - vid, vname

```
1 100GM
2 200GM
3 500GM
```

table_product_variants - pid, vid

```
1 1
1 2
2 1
2 3
3 2
```

How to fetch all products with its corresponding variants without inner loops.

Result:

```
[{
        "pid": "1",
        "pname": "abc",
        "Variants": [{
            "1": "100GM"
        }, {
            "2": "200GM"
        }]
    }, {

        "pid": "2",
        "pname": "xyz",
        "Variants": [{
            "1": "100GM"
        }, {
            "3": "500GM"
        }]

    },

    {

        "pid": "3",
        "pname": "mnop",
        "Variants": [{
            "2": "200GM"
        }]

    }
]
```

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: You can use JOIN, please provide appropriate detail with table structure and data and what you tried for your problem.

Comment: after using join variant data will be available in multiple rows. How to group those rows to get above output.

Comment: Why can you not use loops in PHP? If not I expect GROUP_CONCAT in the select statement will provide you with somewhere to start. I can't provide an answer at the moment but hope that helps

Comment: @Ukuser32 Consider there are 10000 products, inner loop will run 10000 times. That is the reason i want to avoid loop if some better way is possible.